# "kotlin-android-extensions" find id is null in apply

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

When I use `apply`,"kotlin-android-extensions" find id is null

```
   private val nickDialog: NickDialog by lazy {
        NickDialog(this@AccountInformationActivity).apply {
            this.setOnClickConfirmListener {
                account_nick.setRightText(it)
                this.dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
```

> **java.lang.NullPointerException:** Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.cnjnb.wealthstorm.view.TextLineView.setRightText(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference.

But when I use this, it's OK.

```
    private val nickDialog: NickDialog by lazy {
        val a = NickDialog(this@AccountInformationActivity)
        a.setOnClickConfirmListener {
            account_nick.setRightText(it)
            a.dismiss()
        }
        a
    }
```

XML:
account_nick is view'id in my XML

Part of it is :

```
  <com.cnjnb.wealthstorm.view.TextLineView
        android:id="@+id/account_nick"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/account_profession"
        app:leftText="nick"
        app:rightText="bright" />
```

Comment: What is `account_nick`? Can you share its initialization?

Comment: @Ircover account_nick is id in my xml file

Comment: Check your import for synthetic for `account_nick`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the source of your problem is `account_nick` property. When you call it insinde dialogs `apply`, code executes for it - he tries to find that view inside the dialog. While it's activities view, here you got null.

To avoid it you can place `this@YourActivityClass` before `account_nick` call.

```
private val nickDialog: NickDialog by lazy {
    NickDialog(this@AccountInformationActivity).apply {
        this.setOnClickConfirmListener {
            this@AccountInformationActivity.account_nick.setRightText(it)
            this.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```